# How to increase QFrame.HLine line separator width and distance with the other buttons?

Tags: python, qt, button, layout, pyqt5

I got this very tiny `QFrame.HLine` I leaned to do on the thread [Separator in box layout](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/24433-Separator-in-box-layout):

[image]

But I cannot figure out how to increase its size, i.e, makes bigger the spacing between them. This is a Photoshop image of what I am trying to do:

[image]

I tried setting the properties `setLineWidth` and `setMidLineWidth`, but does not matter how big I set their values, the line does not gets bigger.

This is the example code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
import PyQt5

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFrame
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication( sys.argv )
    programWindow = ProgramWindow()

    programWindow.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )

class ProgramWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__( self )
        self.setup_main_window()
        self.create_input_text()
        self.set_window_layout()

    def setup_main_window(self):
        self.resize( 400, 300  )
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget( self.centralwidget )

    def create_input_text(self):
        self.separatorLine = QFrame()
        self.separatorLine.setFrameShape( QFrame.HLine )
        self.separatorLine.setFrameShadow( QFrame.Raised )

        # self.separatorLine.setLineWidth( 150 )
        # self.separatorLine.setMidLineWidth( 150 )

        rect = self.separatorLine.frameRect()
        print( "frameShape: %s" % rect )
        print( "width: %s" % self.separatorLine.width() )
        print( "height: %s" % self.separatorLine.height() )

        self.redoButton = QPushButton( "Redo Operations" )
        self.calculate  = QPushButton( "Compute and Follow" )
        self.open       = QPushButton( "Open File" )
        self.save       = QPushButton( "Save File" )

        self.verticalGridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.redoButton    , 1 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.calculate     , 2 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.separatorLine , 3 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.open          , 4 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.save          , 5 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.setSpacing( 0 )
        self.verticalGridLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        self.innerLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.innerLayout.addLayout( self.verticalGridLayout )

    def set_window_layout(self):
        main_vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout( self.centralwidget )
        main_vertical_layout.addLayout( self.innerLayout )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **QGridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(row, minSize)**
>
> Sets the minimum height of row row to minSize pixels.

---

```
import sys
import PyQt5

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFrame
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication( sys.argv )
    programWindow = ProgramWindow()

    programWindow.show()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )

class ProgramWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__( self )
        self.setup_main_window()
        self.create_input_text()
        self.set_window_layout()

    def setup_main_window(self):
        self.resize( 400, 300  )
        self.centralwidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget( self.centralwidget )

    def create_input_text(self):
        self.separatorLine = QFrame()
        self.separatorLine.setFrameShape( QFrame.HLine )
        self.separatorLine.setFrameShadow( QFrame.Raised )

        # self.separatorLine.setLineWidth( 150 )
        #self.separatorLine.setMidLineWidth( 5 )
        # +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.separatorLine.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.separatorLine.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.separatorLine.setStyleSheet("font: 9pt;")
        self.separatorLine.setLineWidth(0)
        self.separatorLine.setMidLineWidth(10)
        # +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
        

        rect = self.separatorLine.frameRect()
        print( "frameShape: %s" % rect )
        print( "width: %s" % self.separatorLine.width() )
        print( "height: %s" % self.separatorLine.height() )

        self.redoButton = QPushButton( "Redo Operations" )
        self.calculate  = QPushButton( "Compute and Follow" )
        self.open       = QPushButton( "Open File" )
        self.save       = QPushButton( "Save File" )

        self.verticalGridLayout = QGridLayout()
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.redoButton    , 1 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.calculate     , 2 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.separatorLine , 3 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.open          , 4 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.addWidget( self.save          , 5 , 0)
        self.verticalGridLayout.setSpacing( 0 )
        self.verticalGridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(3, 40)               # +++
        self.verticalGridLayout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)

        self.innerLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.innerLayout.addLayout( self.verticalGridLayout )

    def set_window_layout(self):
        main_vertical_layout = QVBoxLayout( self.centralwidget )
        main_vertical_layout.addLayout( self.innerLayout )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for help! Do you also know how to make the line ticker?

Comment: @user I added  the line ticker:)

Comment: Sorry, I mean `thicker` not `ticker`. You make the text bolder, not the separator line. I tried to use `self.separatorLine.setLineWidth( 150 )` but either `self.separatorLine.setLineWidth( 1500 )` does not make it thicker.

Comment: Note that the frame width depends on the frame style, not only the line width and the mid-line width. For example, the style specified by NoFrame always has a frame width of 0, whereas the style Panel has a frame width equivalent to the line width.
I updated the code

Comment: Instead of calling `self.verticalGridLayout.setRowMinimumHeight(3, 40)`, I can just call `self.separatorLine.setMinimumSize( 3, 40 )` directly on each new separator. I had to do this because when I added more new separator lines the `setRowMinimumHeight(3, 40)` stopped working and no minimum space was added anymore.